# jQuery .ajax() and .post() returning no response

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery's .ajax function to make a call to a php page.  I have used this function many times before, and I've never had this problem with it.  No matter what data I pass, no matter what page I call, I get no response.  Using Firebug, I don't even see a response at all associated with the POST request.

My ajax code looks like this:

```
$.post('test_ajax.php', {one : 1, two: 2}, function(data){
    alert(data);
});
```

I have also done this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./test_ajax.php",
    data: {one: 1, two: 2},
    success:function(responseText){
        alert(responseText);
    }
});
```

I have tried it with both relative and absolute URLs - it doesn't seem to have any trouble connecting to the right page, it just doesn't return any response.

The alerts are just blank, the response is interpreted as an empty string.

My PHP code just looks like this:

```
<?php
var_dump($_REQUEST);
die ("Here");
?>
```

But like I said, for some reason there is NO response at all.

Comment: What do you see in Fiddler?  What if you re-issue the request in Fiddler?

Comment: The problem's probably in php / server config.  Check your error log?  Also, try navigating directly to the page in your browser and see what comes up.

Comment: DId you check the server's logs to see what happens on that end of things?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Fiddler.  What is that?

Comment: Are you able to just do a GET on your browser by typing in: `http://whatever.com/text_ajax.php?one=1&two=2` ? You should see the response on your browser page.

Comment: @JonathanM Yes, I can pull up the file in the browser, and it works just fine, I see the request parameters and then the "Here".

Comment: @SamDufel There is nothing about it in the error log, and in the access logs the request looks like it's working just fine.

Comment: @MarcB The server logs look normal - the error log doesn't have anything about this, and the access logs look fine -

`38.73.134.43 - --Username-- [08/May/2012:10:01:06 -0500] "POST /test_ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1667 --Referrer-- "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.168 Safari/535.19"`

Comment: @FrizbeeFanatic14 - the problem doesn't seem to be in any code you've posted.  You'll probably need to provide a link to get an answer.

Comment: What's with the dot-slash at the beginning of the URL? Shouldn't it just be `url: "test_ajax.php",` ? I know in unix that notation stands, but in a URL?

Comment: @JonathanM I'm pretty sure the notation still works.  I have tried it both ways, just to see if it was having trouble finding the file.

Comment: @SamDufel Yeah, I know.  Go to http://dev.vacationcandy.com/results?destination=St+Kitts&arrive=05%2F10%2F2012&depart=06%2F14%2F2012.  It will ask for username/password - use stack/overflow.  The code should be run when you click the red search button near the top, next to the dates.

Comment: Mm, gotta go to work - you're getting a "request canceled" error when that ajax request is being sent.

Comment: @SamDufel Thanks!  I looked to see what might cause that error, and I found out it's when the page refreshes before it finishes the request.  In this instance, the form is submitting for some reason when you click that button (it shouldn't), so when I removed the form it worked!  Thanks a ton, I'll figure out how to get around the problem.

Comment: @SamDufel If you want to post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be getting a "request canceled" error right after the ajax request is sent.

Sorry I didn't have time to finish investigating / determining the actual cause.